# Where is conditional probability in Bayes' paper

Tags: probability

The modern way to get to Bayes' theorem is through conditional probability. How did Bayes get to it? I've read, with crossed eyes, his 1763 paper and I cannot see conditional probability or his theorem in any recognizable form. Price's appendix comes nearly there. Is it implied and I just can't see it? Or worse still, it is explicit and I can't see it.
(I'm not even going to try Laplace.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_towards_solving_a_Problem_in_the_Doctrine_of_Chances#Outline gives a kind of answer, I think.

Comment: @kimchilover: Thanks, this was helpful. At least it pointed me at a few things to reread.